# vs code update what should i do for next?

Tags: software-installation

i am using vs code. after using few days it says me update available to download so i downloaded the update but what should i do next to apply these update the update size in about to 64 MB in a zip file containing different files with different extension. i am new to Ubuntu to not able to apply these update. As i download the update it show me same file which i have been  downloading previously.
 the downloading link is given here : https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/79b44aa704ce542d8ca4a3cc44cfca566e7720f1/code-stable-code_1.21.1-1521038896_amd64.tar.gz

Comment: How did you install Visual Studio Code? The *vscode* snap package is updated automatically, so you don't need to download anything from a link.

Answer (score 1):

There is option to download .deb file. You can open it with "Software Center" and Visual Code will be automatically updated.